# Modify Android Leanback Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tv, leanback

I need to modify the android support v17 leanback library to make my Android TV app be more inline with requirements. I have read that if the library is available to download I can import it as a module to make a local copy. Unfortunately I cannot find it on github and only see that google is providing the leanback sample instead.

What options do I have here? Is there another way I can bring the code local and make changes? The version I am using is leanback-v17-23.1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AOSP code is only updated on major platform releases (i.e., the release of API 23). You'll need to go to `<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/` to get the latest code for any release besides the 23.0.0 release.

Look for the `sources.jar` file located in the `leanback-v17` directory (specifically `<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/leanback-v17/23.2.1/leanback-v17-23.2.1-sources.jar`) and open it with any program that opens zip files.

Comment: Hey you are even a googler!  Now if only I could get you guys to create a TextCardView class in addition to the ImageCardView I wouldnt have to modify the library! ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @osiris355 - why would you need to customize the library to add a new subclass of `BaseCardView`? I'm not sure what a `TextCardView` would be except an `ImageCardView` with a solid background (a `ColorDrawable` set as the image should work). You might consider asking in the [Android TV Developers G+ community](https://plus.google.com/communities/112881895888889393129) as I get the feeling you are doing more than you need to.

Comment: I need to have additional text, statistics, etc where the image normally is so as I have looked futher through the code it looked like I needed to modify leanback. The rest of the card is perfect. Its the area where the image is that I need to change. I was told that I could also just render an image with the text but I didnt want to endorse performance issues since I need to re-render the cards often.